# How to Pass Variables to SqlCommand

Tags: sql, sql-server, c#-4.0, ado.net, sqlcommand

I have searched thoroughly, but could not find a way to `SET` my column data to the  variable that I have initialized using a SQL `UPDATE` statement.

Here is the piece of code that is causing problem:

```
int maxId;
SqlConnection dataConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegConnectionString"].ConnectionString) ;
SqlCommand dataCommand = new SqlCommand("select max(UserID) from Registration", dataConnection) ;
dataConnection.Open();
maxId = Convert.ToInt32(dataCommand.ExecuteScalar());
string Id = maxId.ToString();

// this next line is not working
SqlCommand _setvin = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Registration SET VIN=maxId , Voted=0  WHERE UserID=maxId", dataConnection);
_setvin.ExecuteNonQuery();

dataConnection.Close();
```

Please guide me on how I can correct the commented line above.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
SqlCommand _setvin = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Registration SET VIN=@maxId, Voted=0  WHERE UserID=@maxId", dataConnection);
_setvin.Parameters.Add("@maxId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = maxId;
_setvin.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Sorry about that.. Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to do this:

```
var _setvin = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Registration SET VIN = @maxId, Voted = 0 WHERE UserID = @maxId", dataConnection);
_setvin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@maxId", maxId);
_setvin.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You need to first change your SQL statement to include a parameter for the `maxId`; I'm calling that `@maxId` in your SQL. Then you need to supply a value for that parameter to the command. This is done with the [`Parameters.AddWithValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx) method.

Comment: with ur solution its giving error "Invalid column name" .. **PLEASE NOTE** that maxId is the variable name not column name ... **and i want  to set the column whose name is VIN with the value contained in maxId **

Comment: @Sana I am using `@maxId` as a variable, not a column. The columns involved here are `VIN`, `Voted`, and `UserID`.

Comment: it does not work here ... "invalid column name 'maxId' exception being catched with the solution u jx gave

Comment: @Sana Then you're not copying my code correctly, as I don't make any reference to `maxId` **as a column**.